# linearly dependent or independent matrices in $M_{22}$

Tags: linear-algebra

This was a question from my textbook.

Determine whether the matrices are linearly independent or dependent.

$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

in $M_{22}$

What does it mean in $M_{22}$? I realize I am not given too much context, but that's all that the question asks.

Comment: @DaphnaKeidar In this case we are interested on the vector space structure.

Comment: @DaphnaKeidar: I meant that linear combinations arises in the context of vector spaces. Hence the structure of a field here is irrelevant. And by the way, $M_{2\times 2}$ is **not** a field, but a ring. The matrix $diag(1,0,)$ doesn't have an inverse with respect to the matrix product.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that $M_{22}$ is the space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices with real entries. Can you find constants $a,b,c$ which are not all zero and satisfy
$$ a \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix} + 
b\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} + 
c \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}? $$
If the answer is yes, then the matrices are linearly dependent, and otherwise they are linearly independent by definition.

A hint to get you started: Looking at the top left entry, we see that we must have $b=-a$, and looking at the top right entry, we see that $c=-2b=2a$. What happens if you insert those relations into the equation above?

Comment: Couldn't you also just put a+0+a+2a, b+2b+2b+1, and 0+c+2c+1 into a matrix and calculate the determinent? If it is 0 then the system is 0 then the system is dependent?

Comment: Or is that what you were getting at?

Comment: @user583753 I'm not sure what you mean by putting those values in a matrix.

Comment: I put an answer as to what I meant. Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

Write $M_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$ $M_2 =\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ $M_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$.

We can clearly see that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are independant.

Now, can we find $(\alpha,\beta) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\alpha \cdot M_1 + \beta \cdot M_2 = M_3$?

We've got the followging system:

\begin{cases} \alpha + \beta = 0 \\ 2\beta = 1 \\ \alpha + 2\beta = 2
\\ 2\alpha + \beta = 1 \end{cases}

If we add up the last two lines, we get $3(\alpha + \beta) = 3$, which shows that the system is unsolvable since the first line tells us $\alpha + \beta = 0$.

Hence, your three matrices are linearly independant.

Answer (score 0):

$M_{2,2}$ 
means the set all $2$by $2$ matrices.

Your three matrices are linearly independent. You can verify it by showing that if $$c_1M_1+c_2M_2+c_3M_3=0\implies c_1=c_2=c_3=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrices as vectors in $K^4$. the coefficients of the matrices are their coordinates in the standard basis:
$$ E_1=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},\quad E_2=\begin{bmatrix} 
0&1 \\ 0&0
\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{\&c.}$$
The condition of independence is that the matrix of their coordinates:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 &1
\end{bmatrix}$$
has rank $3$, i.e. there exists a sub-$\,3\times 3$-matrix with a non-zero determinant.

Answer (score 0):

$$a \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix} + 
b\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} + 
c \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$a+b=0$$$$2b+c=0$$$$a+2b+2c=0$$$$2a+b+c=0$$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 &2 & 0 \\ 
2&1&1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then row reducing we get

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0&0&0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since the last row is of trivial solution then the system of equations are linearly independent. Is this a correct approach? And the determinant is obviously also 0.